# Why is my $_REQUEST['request'] variable undefined (when visiting Endpoints of API)

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest

I followed a tutorial [here](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) to create a RESTful API with PHP.

I'm running the project on localhost however I'm getting the following error when trying to view the endpoint suggested in the tutorial (api/v1/example):

```
Notice: Undefined index: request in C:\wamp64\www\API\api.php on line 8
```

(Note: see the api.php file down below.)

This request index should be set in the htaccess file so I think that's where the problem is. (My apologies if this is something simple but i've tried to find out myself with no luck.) Can you help?

In the tutorial we create:

1. A htaccess file to configure how the web server should handle requests to files within the directory of the project.
2. An Abstract class to handle the parsing of the URI and returning the
       response.
3. A Concrete class that consists of the endpoints for the
   API.

## htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

## Abstract class

```
<?php
    abstract class API
    {
        /**
         * Property: method
         * The HTTP method this request was made in, either GET, POST, PUT or DELETE
         */
        protected $method = '';
        /**
         * Property: endpoint
         * The Model requested in the URI. eg: /files
         */
        protected $endpoint = '';
        /**
         * Property: verb
         * An optional additional descriptor about the endpoint, used for things that can
         * not be handled by the basic methods. eg: /files/process
         */
        protected $verb = '';
        /**
         * Property: args
         * Any additional URI components after the endpoint and verb have been removed, in our
         * case, an integer ID for the resource. eg: /<endpoint>/<verb>/<arg0>/<arg1>
         * or /<endpoint>/<arg0>
         */
        protected $args = Array();
        /**
         * Property: file
         * Stores the input of the PUT request
         */
         protected $file = Null;

        /**
         * Constructor: __construct
         * Allow for CORS, assemble and pre-process the data
         */
        public function __construct($request) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
            header("Content-Type: application/json");

            $this->args = explode('/', rtrim($request, '/'));
            $this->endpoint = array_shift($this->args);
            if (array_key_exists(0, $this->args) && !is_numeric($this->args[0])) {
                $this->verb = array_shift($this->args);
            }

            $this->method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
            if ($this->method == 'POST' && array_key_exists('HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD', $_SERVER)) {
                if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'] == 'DELETE') {
                    $this->method = 'DELETE';
                } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
                    $this->method = 'PUT';
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Unexpected Header");
                }
            }

            switch($this->method) {
            case 'DELETE':
            case 'POST':
                $this->request = $this->_cleanInputs($_POST);
                break;
            case 'GET':
                $this->request = $this->_cleanInputs($_GET);
                break;
            case 'PUT':
                $this->request = $this->_cleanInputs($_GET);
                $this->file = file_get_contents("php://input");
                break;
            default:
                $this->_response('Invalid Method', 405);
                break;
            }
        }
        public function processAPI() {
            if (method_exists($this, $this->endpoint)) {
                return $this->_response($this->{$this->endpoint}($this->args));
            }
            return $this->_response("No Endpoint: $this->endpoint", 404);
        }

        private function _response($data, $status = 200) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 " . $status . " " . $this->_requestStatus($status));
            return json_encode($data);
        }

        private function _cleanInputs($data) {
            $clean_input = Array();
            if (is_array($data)) {
                foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
                    $clean_input[$k] = $this->_cleanInputs($v);
                }
            } else {
                $clean_input = trim(strip_tags($data));
            }
            return $clean_input;
        }

        private function _requestStatus($code) {
            $status = array(  
                200 => 'OK',
                404 => 'Not Found',   
                405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
                500 => 'Internal Server Error',
            ); 
            return ($status[$code])?$status[$code]:$status[500]; 
        }



    }
    ?>
```

## Concrete class

```
<?php
require_once 'API.class.php';

class MyAPI extends API
{
    protected $FacebookUser;

    public function __construct($request, $origin) {
        parent::__construct($request);
        //I removed the User and API key code here until they are set up properly
    }

    /**
     * Example of an Endpoint
     */
     protected function example() {
        if ($this->method == 'GET') {
           return "Endpoint is working"; 
        } else {
            return "Only accepts GET requests";
        }
     }
 }
?>
```

## api.php

```
<?php
require_once 'MyAPI.class.php';
// Requests from the same server don't have a HTTP_ORIGIN header
if (!array_key_exists('HTTP_ORIGIN', $_SERVER)) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}
try {
    //the following $_REQUEST['request'] variable is not set.
    $API = new MyAPI($_REQUEST['request'], $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    echo $API->processAPI();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(Array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
}
?>
```

Comment: are you sending request variable on sending request?

Comment: If you visit `api/v1/foo` does it work?

Comment: @Progrock I just tried that. it gives the same error.

Comment: Your file path differs from your .htaccess rewrite rule path.  What's your file hierarchy and where is your .htaccess file placed?

Comment: @Progrock I have a project folder called API and I have all my files in there on the root level (.htaccess, api.php, API.class.php and MyAPI.class.php). and then I visit this endpoint: http://localhost/API/api/v1/example

Comment: @PankajMakwana thanks. The request variable should be set in the htaccess file when the rewrite is performed.

Comment: If your .htaccess is in API folder, then the rewrite rule should push the request through to a subfolder and file at API/api/v1/api.php so this feels wrong.  What is your document root?

Comment: @Progrock Ok. I'm using wamp64 so the www folder is the document root. So project folder is: C:\wamp64\www\API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your .htaccess file you'll need a hierarchy more like this:

```
API
├── api
│   └── v1
│       └── api.php
└── .htaccess
```

Where API is currently a subfolder of your document root (in the future you will likely make API your document root or move files accordingly).

Contents of `API/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Contents of `API/api/v1/api.php` (to check rewrite is working):

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Then requests for:

```
example.com/API/api/v1/foo
```

Should be rewritten to your api.php file (via the rewrite rule) and api.php should output:

```
array(1) { ["request"]=> string(3) "foo" }
```

Comment: thank you. With inspiration from your answer I didn't change the file structure. I just changed the .htaccess file as follows:
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule> and this is working now (the request variable is being set when visiting http://localhost/API/example or http://localhost/API/api/v1/example). As you can see I also took out the two RewriteCond lines as these were not allowing the RewriteRule to proceed. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yes, you can do it like that.  I'd keep the other two lines, that works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

`$_REQUEST` is an array of request variables sent by the client. The key `request` is not guaranteed to exist inside of this array. Trying using a debugger or `var_dump` to show the contents of the array.

Perhaps if you update your question with the request that you are sendings somebody will be able to guide you further.

Comment: Thank you. My understanding of the process is that the request variable is set in the htaccess file here: (RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]) and should contain the full URL which will then be parsed in the constructor of the Abstract API.class as you can see on this line in the constructor: $this->args = explode('/', rtrim($request, '/')); ... the idea is to retrieve the endpoint from the URI string from there. I outputted the $_REQUEST variable and it is empty... Do you think it is my htaccess that is not performing the rewrite properly?